# Create new sheets from a column of cells while avoiding duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I have several long columns of data that needs to be sorted. In the first column i have the names of the sheets. But there are several duplicates in there that give me an error message as each sheet needs a unique name. The second and all other columns are to be distributed among the sheets but so far that is not my worry as I can't make the first part not give me an error message. It works fine until it hits a duplicate entry.

```
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sheetname As Variant
    Dim sheetexists As Boolean
    Dim cellname As Variant
    Dim worksheet_count As Integer
       
    Dim mysheet As Worksheet
    
        'Find the last non-blank cell in column A1
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        worksheet_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        sheetexists = False
        For j = 1 To worksheet_count
            sheetname = Cells(i, 1).Value
            cellname = Sheets(j).Name
            If cellname = sheetname Then
                sheetexists = True
                a = 5
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
                
        If sheetexists = False Then
            'create sheet, rename sheet
                
            Worksheets(1).Select
            sheetname = Cells(i, 1).Value
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = sheetname
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: What error and on which code line?

Comment: You need to qualify (add a sheet reference) to `sheetname = Cells(i, 1).Value` or Cells will refer to the active sheet. Eg `Sheets(1).Cells(i,1).Value`. You can also move that line to before the j loop.

Comment: I changed the code around a little bit and i have no clue why this isn't working when i went into break mode it shoved me the if statement is true on both end but it doesn't run it. Which in turn puts out the error for "that name is already taken. Try a different one.

Comment: @jon update your question with the code you have now

Comment: Just did cellname and sheetname in my case both equal "LEKARNA ŠKOFJA LOKA" Basicly sheetexists wont turn to true stays false

Comment: @CDP1802 I changed the code around as you suggested that fixed it. Thank you very much I am still dumb found though as in break mode it showed me something else...

Comment: @Jon The problem was checking cellname against Cells(i, 1).Value on the activesheet . The active sheet will have changed to the new sheet so  Cells(i, 1).Value would be ""

Answer (score 0):

Below is a somewhat less cumbersome way to do what you want.
Note: It assumes sheet names are in row 2+ of column 1 of the Active Sheet (per your code):

```
Sub CreateSheets()

    Dim lgErr&, rgRg As Range, rgShNames As Range
    
    Set rgShNames = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    
    For Each rgRg In rgShNames.Cells
    
        If rgRg <> "" Then
            On Error Resume Next: Err.Clear
                With Sheets(rgRg.Value): End With
            lgErr = Err: On Error GoTo 0
            
            If lgErr <> 0 Then
                Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Name = rgRg
            End If
        End If
    
    Next rgRg

End Sub
```